# Very slow smtp server response

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, smtp, fedora

I recently have created a server on https://www.scaleway.com/. Server's OS is Fedora22. I installed a SMTP server (postfix). It works fine, but I have very slow response from it. Any message, that I send from php script or from ruby redmine, it makes the page load very long. When I try to send message like this:

```
echo "TEXT" | mail -s "Hello world" mail@gmail.com
```

I got this message in 1 or 2 minutes.

Logs from postfix status command:

```
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-10-25 14:04:52 EDT; 2min 1s ago
  Process: 1448 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1467 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1464 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1459 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1537 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─1537 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─1538 pickup -l -t unix -u
           ├─1539 qmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─1605 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress=
           ├─1606 proxymap -t unix -u
           ├─1607 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
           ├─1608 cleanup -z -t unix -u
           └─1609 smtp -t unix -u

Oct 25 14:04:51 scw-5a11dd postfix/postfix-script[1535]: starting the Postfix mail system
Oct 25 14:04:51 scw-5a11dd postfix/master[1537]: daemon started -- version 3.0.2, configuration /etc/postfix
Oct 25 14:04:52 scw-5a11dd systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Oct 25 14:06:08 scw-5a11dd postfix/smtpd[1605]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 25 14:06:08 scw-5a11dd postfix/smtpd[1605]: E16B941726: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 25 14:06:08 scw-5a11dd postfix/cleanup[1608]: E16B941726: message-id=<201510251806.t9PI68aj001554@scw-5a11dd>
Oct 25 14:06:08 scw-5a11dd postfix/qmgr[1539]: E16B941726: from=<root@scw-5a11dd>, size=682, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 25 14:06:08 scw-5a11dd postfix/smtpd[1605]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Oct 25 14:06:09 scw-5a11dd postfix/smtp[1609]: E16B941726: to=<wkyborgw@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, del...- gsmtp)
Oct 25 14:06:09 scw-5a11dd postfix/qmgr[1539]: E16B941726: removed
```

I don't know what to do. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: It looks like everything happened in 1 second. Have you tried anything besides gmail?

Comment: If you only need to send out email, alerts, contact forms etc. you could also consider a lightweight SMTP solution like msmtp which isn't a complete MTA like Postfix. Your log indeed shows the mail sent within a second, so the delay may be on the receiving side, perhaps seeing it as suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your Postfix config it is certain this is the issue. However check the postfix documentation -

http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html

and look for the TarPit settings. See if your configuration smtpd_error_sleep_time is set to 2 minutes.